# How to get ajax data to render on component in react flux store?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to get data from flux store to render on some components. How to do that in flux store. Here, i have added my sample code, which i have tried.

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
var newData;
class EventLists extends EventEmitter {
    getAll() {
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data) {
                newData = data;
            }
        });
        return newData;
    }
};

const eventLists = new EventLists;

export default eventLists;
```

Comment: You should probably go back and read through the Flux documentation some more and try to get a better grasp on what each aspect of Flux is intended to achieve.  The code you have here seems to be a combination of an ActionCreator and a Store, but those are two very different things.

Comment: @gravityplanx, Yes, i read flux documention and done such a way. I posted one more question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433513/how-to-use-external-image-url-with-react-flux-store. How to cache external image url in react flux?